# How to call a model from a controller concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, namespaces

I have a model

```
models/
  contract.rb
```

and I have a controller concern

```
controllers/
  concerns/
    search.rb
```

that looks like this

```
module Search
  def get_contracts    
    c = Contract.new
  end
end
```

When I try to call get_contracts I get this error:

> Unable to autoload constant Search::Contract, expected
>   /Users/me/myapp/app/controllers/concerns/search/contract.rb to define
>   it

Is there a better way to access a model from a controller concern?

Comment: it looks like you also have a `Contract` module, that's why you get that error. You'd need to somehow use `Contract` with a namespace, or try using `::Contract`. But anyway, you have another module with the same name that generates this conflict, I think you should namespace things so you don't get these errors.

Comment: thank you, using double colons like ::Contract works

Comment: Although double colons `::` will work a carefully designed name-spacing strategy is usually preferable.